# Hibernate UPDATE via createSQLQuery used with RETURNING

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I was trying to make an UPDATE statement that updates few columns and return the updated row as an Entity.

Here is the code:

```
User user = (User) session
    .createSQLQuery(
      "UPDATE \"user\" " + 
      "SET chips_balance=chips_balance + 100" +
      "WHERE id=118 " +
      "RETURNING *")
    .addEntity(User.class)
    .uniqueResult();
```

It party works, meaning, it really returns an updated 'User' entity, BUT it doesn't update the actual data in the DB table!

Is there something to do in order to make it work well?

Thank you!

Comment: I've executed this query directly in pgadmin (PostgreSQL) and it works! meaning something in my Hibernate way is not correct !

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that in this case you need to create a transaction and commit it.